Return parenthesis has to be on the same line in JS
The following code works (snippet from React Component JSX ):
return (
        <div>
            <h1>Manage Categories</h1>
......

But this doesnt:
 return 
(
        <div>
            <h1>Manage Categories</h1>
....

I thought whitespace didnt matter in JS. I get an unreachable code error.

You've already shared the solution...

That's not a white space issue. It's a new line issue.  JS does it's best to figure out where one expression ends, and the next begins.  You've put a line break after the return statement, JS thinks that's the end of the expression.
